# How can we hide cancel button that download manager shows in notification

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am new to download manager I want to control the download cancel from app but not from notification above I was unable to get any information from google. What I want is that notification shown by download manager should not contain any cancel button.

Comment: show your code snippet...

Comment: request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(
            AndroidApp.context(),
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
                    + File.separator
                    + mediaName,
            mediaName + videoId + SUFFIX_SEPARATOR + suffix
        )

        // submit the downloading task to download manager.
        val dm = AndroidApp.context().getSystemService(
            Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE
        ) as DownloadManager

        return dm.enqueue(request)

Answer (score 0):

The Download Manager of android system will use it's default buttons. You can't hide that **Cancel** button. 
If you want to handle this functionality in your application, You have to code your own download manager.